# SQL query how to SELECT data even criteria not match in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-generation

I am sure there must be a relatively straightforward way to do this, but it is escaping me at the moment. Suppose I have a SQL table like this:

```
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|type |value |  Monthly  |
+=====+======+=====+=====+
|  a  |  5   |  Jan      |  << a,Jan      
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|  a  |  3   |  Feb      |  << a,Feb      
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|  a  |  7   |  April    |  << a,April    
+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

I group my query by type and monthly, let say i search for the value from jan to april, in this case, March doenst have any value, but i still want it to be display 0, how to do like this? :

```
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|type |value |  Monthly  |
+=====+======+=====+=====+
|  a  |  5   |  Jan      |  << a,Jan      
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|  a  |  3   |  Feb      |  << a,Feb      
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|  a  |  0   |  Mar      |  << a,Mar
+-----+------+-----+-----+
|  a  |  7   |  April    |  << a,April    
+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Check the datetime-generation tagged questions -- I've answered various similar questions in the past.  Basically, you need to create a derived table of all the months, and LEFT JOIN your table to it.

Comment: Additionally, for consistent matching of your months, you have some at 3 char, yet April is fully spelled out. Do one or the other, not both.  Easier to join based on left 3 of a monthly name reference than sometimes 3, sometimes full length.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a table with a list of months (e.g. month_id, month_name). You can then do something like this:

```
SELECT t.*, m.* FROM months m LEFT JOIN table t ON m.month_id = t.month_id
```

Otherwise, there's no way for the query to know that there's such a thing as 'March'.

Comment: Basically the idea is fine, but it should be `months LEFT JOIN table`, not the other way round.

Comment: any other solution without involves other table?

Comment: Good point Andriy M, I fixed that up. @phobia_coder No, I don't know of another way. You need to define the months.

Answer (score 0):

in sql make your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (value='0' OR value='yourcondition') AND..
```

Comment: No -- there are no values for March in the table.

Comment: the value is not a single value, its based on count value for the same type